# Returning dynamic query results from PL/PGSQL function, multiple rows

Tags: postgresql, plpgsql, dynamicquery

I work on the following test table:

```
select * from test;
 id | broker  | affiliate | leads 
----+---------+-----------+-------
  1 | broker1 | aff1      |     1
  2 | broker1 | aff2      |     2
  3 | broker2 | aff2      |     4
(3 rows)
```

I want to create a function which will accept `group by` column name and `where` predicate. Here is a working example of the function:

```
DROP FUNCTION report2(TEXT,TEXT);
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION report2(
    group_by_column_name TEXT,
    sql_where TEXT
)
RETURNS RECORD
AS $$
DECLARE
    query TEXT;
    result_row RECORD;
BEGIN
    query := 'SELECT ';
    IF group_by_column_name <> '' THEN
        query := query || group_by_column_name || ', ';
    END IF;
    query := query || 'sum(leads) FROM test';
    IF sql_where <> '' THEN
        query := query || ' WHERE ' || sql_where;
    END IF;
    IF group_by_column_name <> '' THEN
        query := query || ' GROUP BY(' || group_by_column_name || ')';
    END IF;
    RAISE NOTICE 'query: %;', query;

    

    EXECUTE query INTO result_row;
    RETURN result_row;

END
$$ LANGUAGE 'plpgsql';
```

and it's usage:

```
select report2('broker', '');
NOTICE:  query: SELECT broker, sum(leads) FROM test GROUP BY(broker);
   report2   
-------------
 (broker1,3)
(1 row)
```

I'm trying to get not only a first row of the query but all the rows (obviously).

I tried the following:

```
DROP FUNCTION report2(TEXT,TEXT);
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION report2(
    group_by_column_name TEXT,
    sql_where TEXT
)
RETURNS SETOF RECORD
AS $$
DECLARE
    query TEXT;
    result_row RECORD;
BEGIN
    query := 'SELECT ';
    IF group_by_column_name <> '' THEN
        query := query || group_by_column_name || ', ';
    END IF;
    query := query || 'sum(leads) FROM test';
    IF sql_where <> '' THEN
        query := query || ' WHERE ' || sql_where;
    END IF;
    IF group_by_column_name <> '' THEN
        query := query || ' GROUP BY(' || group_by_column_name || ')';
    END IF;
    RAISE NOTICE 'query: %;', query;

--  Does not worK:
--     FOR result_row IN EXECUTE query
--     LOOP
--         RETURN NEXT result_row;
--     END LOOP;

-- Does not worK:
--     RETURN QUERY EXECUTE query;



END
$$ LANGUAGE 'plpgsql';
```

In both cases, with `FOR` or `RETURN QUERY`, the error occurs:

```
NOTICE:  query: SELECT broker, sum(leads) FROM test GROUP BY(broker);
ERROR:  materialize mode required, but it is not allowed in this context
CONTEXT:  PL/pgSQL function report2(text,text) line 21 at RETURN NEXT
```

From the [docs][1]:

```
If multiple rows are returned, only the first will be assigned to the INTO variable(s).
```

So, how is it possible to get the entire results?

```
  [1]: https://(https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/plpgsql-statements.html#PLPGSQL-STATEMENTS-EXECUTING-DYN)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would return `setof json` instead of `record` because the number of result rows varies and `json` is more usable than `record`. So here is the function:

```sql
create function report2(arg_group text default '', arg_where text default '')
returns setof json language plpgsql as
$$
begin
  return query execute format(
    'select to_json(t) from (select %s sum(leads) from test %s %s) t', 
    case when arg_group = '' then '' else arg_group || ',' end,
    case when arg_where = '' then '' else 'where ' || arg_where end,
    case when arg_group = '' then '' else 'group by ' || arg_group end
   ); 
end; 
$$

select report2('broker');
```

| report2 |
| --- |
| {"broker":"broker1","sum":3} |
| {"broker":"broker2","sum":4} |

Answer (score 1):

You're using a [set-returning function](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/xfunc-sql.html#XFUNC-SQL-FUNCTIONS-RETURNING-SET) in the select list. It's possible for SRF with return types that are either clearly specified or predictable, but your set-of-record-returning monstrosity doesn't qualify.

Technically, the function you presented is perfectly correct, fine and usable - you *can* call it, just not the way you tried. Look: [*(demo at db<>fiddle)*](https://dbfiddle.uk/PyJ5sdle)

```sql
select * from report2('broker', '')as(col1 text,col2 bigint);
```

| col1 | col2 |
| --- | --- |
| broker1 | 3 |
| broker2 | 4 |

You can even get it to pack those back up into records:

```
select row(col1,col2) from report2('broker', '')as(col1 text,col2 bigint);
```

| row |
| --- |
| (broker1,3) |
| (broker2,4) |

You can even build that into the function if you use the `row()` constructor to prevent unpacking:

```sql
     FOR result_row IN EXECUTE query
     LOOP
         RETURN NEXT row(result_row);
     END LOOP;
```

And then you can openly say it's returning *just records* (the *non-of-your-business* type):

```sql
select * from report2('broker', '')as(r record);
```

| r |
| --- |
| (broker1,3) |
| (broker2,4) |

---

I have very little idea what it is you're trying to do, why and why this way, but [polymorphic types](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/extend-type-system.html#EXTEND-TYPES-POLYMORPHIC) would probably help, packing things into a [`jsonb`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/datatype-json.html) [suggested](https://stackoverflow.com/a/77672339/5298879) by [@Stefanov.sm](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2302032/stefanov-sm) *might* be easier if you don't mind wrapping and unwrapping, casting and re-casting things back and forth. [PL/pgSQL manual](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/plpgsql.html) will definitely help.

---

If you want to json-wrap results, `jsonb` offers more performance through better [indexing](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/datatype-json.html#JSON-INDEXING), more flexibility thanks to additional [functions and operators](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-json.html) than regular `json`, plus `jsonb` automatically cleans up insignificant whitespace, orders and deduplicates your keys, and is more compact to store&transfer.:

```sql
create function report2(group_by_column_name text default null, 
                        sql_where            text default 'true')
returns setof jsonb language plpgsql as $$ begin 
return query execute format(' 
  select to_jsonb(a) from (select %1$s sum(leads) from test where %2$s %3$s)a '
 , group_by_column_name||',' 
 , sql_where 
 , 'group by '||group_by_column_name
); end $$;
```

Default `where true` condition gets optimized away while saving argument checks. You don't have to check if the group by column is null/empty - if it is, `||` will nullify both the comma and `group by` literals. `null||'something'` yields `null`, and giving that to `format()` placeholder `%s` just doesn't put anything there.

The function [runs the same, just in less text](https://dbfiddle.uk/rxIrUKgt).